# How to close mongodb connection using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Hi can anyone give me the right way to close mongodb connection using mongoose. I've tried to check many resources, but couldn't find the thing that I'm looking for. I don't understand when is the time to close it. Can anyone give the full example for it.

Is it like this?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = () => {
   mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
   console.log(err, "ERROR");
   process.exit(1);
});
// disconnect here?
mongoose.disconnect()
};
```

or is like this after every query then close?

```
  const mongoose = require("mongoose");

  static async getBestSellingProducts(cb) {
      try {
        let results = await ProductModel.find(
          {
            stock: { $gte: 1 },
            sold: { $gt: 0 },
          },
           "dbId name photoURL sold",
         {
           sort: { sold: -1 },
           limit: 9,
         }
         ).exec();

         cb(null, results);
         // disocnnect here?
         mongoose.disconnect();
      } catch (err) {
            cb(err, null);
            // disconnect here
            mongoose.disconnect();
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't close the connection after every request if you want your program to do any requests afterwards. It does make sense to close it when your program stops, even though you don't technically  have to do it.

```
process.on('exit', function (){
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: Where should I put above code can you provide me the full example? or just replace the `process.exit(1)` to your code? sorry if this sounds silly. I'm a beginner in backend role

Comment: Just place it anywhere on the top-level of your index.js or whatever file your entry point is.