# How to close all database connections - moongose

Tags: mongoose

Seems when I connect to `mongodb` using `connect` `api` of `mongoose`, I get an array of connections within the `connection` object

```
const connection = await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
        var dbClient = connection.connections[0].client;
```

If I want to close the connection, do I need to go through each `connection` or is there a higher level api which could close all connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  :     mongoose.disconnect();

Mongoose reference : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#Connection.prototype.close()
Here is reference link : [How to close mongodb connection using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71762884/how-to-close-mongodb-connection-using-mongoose)